# TypeScript - Combine two interfaces and making some of its members mandatory

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have the following two interfaces **that cannot be modified**:

```
interface User {
  username: string;
  email?: string;
  age?: number;
  country?: string;
}

interface Player {
  room: number;
  group?: string;
  device?: string;
}
```

I want to combine them into just one inteface: `Member` and at the same time making the fields: `User['email']` and `Player['group']` mandatory (just those 2).

I tried the following (just as an starting point (TBD)):

```
// please edit this code accordingly
interface Member extends User, Player  {}
```

Then, the expected result is to get an error on:

```
const member: Member = {
  username: 'bill.gates',
  // email: 'bill.gates@microsoft.com',
  age: 50,
  room: 5,
  // group: 'A',
}
```

since `email` and `group` are not specified.

Here you have a [Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdrIN4ChnICumUIcAthAFzLphSgDmA3PshOXMADYD8NdBiBZs4jCP2QhC5AEbRWBBAHtC4KAE9JgpqwC+uXKEixEKAArc4GrHgJRly8jWlyFbRg8IAHbfV1sACYQAG7ASH5CIgZG4NDwSMgAshzyUOwAHpAggehoJAA0yJbWWDgxKiB0yJRuUDQpdcgAvDhsxNBklDQA5LI83AB0jHCQ6D0FbAD0U+ycPL393EMjYwAC5OEO6MowYIMq5BOi4jQArAAMk-aOzshn18gzyJ6q3r0AgscGQA).

Thanks!

Comment: remove `?` from interface to make it mandatory field !

Comment: the two origin interfaces cannot be modified

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve that with a combination of `Pick`, `Required` and `Omit` from the [Utility Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html).

```
type Member = Required<Pick<User & Player, 'email' | 'group'>> & Omit<User & Player, 'email' | 'group'>;


/*
Type '{ username: string; age: number; room: number; }' is not assignable to type 'Member'.
  Type '{ username: string; age: number; room: number; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Required<Pick<User & Player, "email" | "group">>': email, group(2322)
*/
const member: Member = {
  username: 'bill.gates',
  // email: 'bill.gates@microsoft.com',
  age: 50,
  room: 5,
  // group: 'A',
}
```

Here is a [working playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=23&ssc=2&pln=14&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdrIN4ChnICumUIcAthAFzLphSgDmA3PshOXMADYD8NdBiBZs4jCP2QhC5AEbRWBBAHtC4KAE9JgpqwC+uXKEixEKAArc4GrHgJRly8jWlyFbRg8IAHbfV1sACYQAG7ASH5CIga4YBreKACyHPJQyAC8yABKEACOhMBQEIEAPObhANYlGFgAZMiW1tAANMgA5Bxc3G3IAD7tnqrebQB8I8j1APLkwGDVJBMNVjZQrR2cPD39bYM+o6yGKiB0yJRuUDTJ5xk4bMTQZJQ0bbI83AB0jHCQ6G3NbAB6AHsDbcZ6vbgfL4-AACMwQDnQyhgYHeKnIf1E4hoAFYAAz-eyOZzIHGE5BA5C7bzPACCmIMQA)

Answer (score 1):

Define Member like this:

```
interface Member extends User, Player  {
    email: string;
    group: string;
}
```

Comment: Way more simple than my solution ;) I like that

Comment: @ThomasThiebaud Thanks, and it still respect the type of each key, e.g. email cannot be number.